# XSLT1.0 maintaining count of child node for generating Id

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to count the no. of child nodes for a particular repeating Parent node.
I need this count to maintain id for a particular element after transformation.

Following is the format of request.xml which I have

```
<Party><Notes><Notes><Party>
<Party><Notes><Notes></Party>
```

The tranformed xml should be :

```
<Attachment id=1></Attachment>
<Attachment id=2></Attachment>
<Attachment id=3></Attachment>
<Attachment id=4></Attachment>
```

I tried using :

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('Attachment',count(preceding-sibling::Notes))" />
```

but its not giving correct values.
Any guidance would help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: `<Attachment id=1></Attachment>` is NOT valid XML. It needs quotes

Comment: `<Party><Notes><Notes><Party>
<Party><Notes><Notes></Party>` is not valid XML. It is not clear how many child nodes you have. Please correct it - only you know what it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `count(preceding::Notes)+1`, but I prefer to use `xsl:number`.

Example...

**XML** (fixed to be well-formed)

```
<request>
    <Party>
        <Notes/>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <Notes/>
    </Party>
</request>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Notes">
        <Attachment>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:number level="any"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </Attachment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Attachment id="1"/>
<Attachment id="2"/>
```